# Form in a modal needs to display result in same modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form in a modal box and the form displays result form database which us good. This takes me to a page called dutydata.php but i want the results to be displayed in the same modal box. That is when i click submit button, it displays my result on the same modal box.

The html form code:

```
<form name="" method="POST" action="dutydata.php" validate>
    <input type="text" name="military_id">
    <button type="submit" name="verify">VIEW</button>
</form>
```

The javascript code that displays the modal:

```
    <script>
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
    btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
    }
    </script>
```

the php code of duty data

```
    <?php
    require ('dbconnection.php');
    ?>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['verify'])) {
    $set = $_POST['military_id'];
    $show = " SELECT * FROM profile WHERE military_id = '{$set}' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $show) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $military_id=$row['military_id'];
        $first_name=$row['first_name'];
        $last_name=$row['last_name'];
        $paygrade=$row['paygrade'];
        $military_rank=$row['military_rank'];
        $mission_country=$row['mission_country'];
        $duty_status=$row['duty_status'];
        $photo=$row['photo'];

    }
    }
    else {
        echo "Not Found";
    }

    ?>
    <table width="398" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td height="26" colspan="2">Your Information</td>
        <td><div align="right"><a href="index.php">Close</a></div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="129" rowspan="5"><img src="<?php echo $photo ?>" width="129" height="129" alt="no photo found" /></td>
        <td width="82" valign="top"><div align="left">Military ID.:</div></td>
        <td width="165" valign="top"><?php echo $military_id ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td valign="top"><div align="left">First Name:</div></td>
        <td valign="top"><?php echo $last_name ?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
            <td valign="top"><div align="left">Last Name:</div></td>
        <td valign="top"><?php echo $first_name ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td valign="top"><div align="left">Pay Grade:</div></td>
        <td valign="top"><?php echo $paygrade ?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
            <td valign="top"><div align="left">Rank:</div></td>
        <td valign="top"><?php echo $military_rank ?></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
            <td valign="top"><div align="left">Mission Country:</div></td>
        <td valign="top"><?php echo $mission_country ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
            <td valign="top"><div align="left">Duty Status:</div></td>
        <td valign="top"><?php echo $duty_status ?></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

this is the image
        (https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xlU3.jpg)

and this the updated image
        (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRnV2.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Then you've to change the type of the button first to `button` to prevent the submition and attach click event to this button and send an ajax request.

**HTML :**

```
<form name="" method="POST" action="dutydata.php" validate>
    <input type="text" name="military_id">
    <button type="button " name="verify">VIEW</button>
</form>
```

**JS :**

```
//Attach click event to the button
$('[name="verify"]').on('click', function(){

    //Send a post request to the 'dutydata.php' and get the result
    $.post('dutydata.php',{military_id: $('[name="military_id"]').val(),verify: $('[name="verify"]').val()}, function(result){

        //Append the result where you want
        $('#myModal form').after( result )
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for swift reply Zak. So I did your answer but it ended up showing undefined variables, but also the results doesn't enter the modal box, it just scatters around the rest of the page. Please i have to get this to work more help please

Comment: Can anyone please help?

Comment: Check plz if the page will submit when you click the button.

Comment: The page submits and shows the result up in dutydata.php. But if I use your javascript code above, it returns undefined variables and also doesn't enter the modal box

Comment: I am so grateful for your help. There's progress. So I have updated my question with an image so you will see what's happening still.

Comment: I wouldn't have gone this far if not for your help. I would be a big liar if I say there's been no progress. Please I just updated my question. There's a new image. You will see what's up after the new edit.

Comment: Anyone solution please?

Comment: Do you have the page online ?

Comment: No I don't have it online